# geth and mist: Error starting protocol stack: datadir already used by another process

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

I am runing the mist wallet app.

In `Terminal` (macos), I also want to start a miner process `geth --etherbase 1 --mine  --port 0`

But `geth --mine` failed with this error message:

> Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: datadir already used by another
>   process

Is there anyway I can have both programs to run concurrently?

Comment: I dont think that is possible, because both process would want to modify the blocks at the same time, may be you can try with separate `datadir`, not sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible:

1) Start geth in Terminal first:

```
> geth --mine
```

2) Launch Mist, but also from Terminal so you can pass commands to make it connect to the IPC created by geth.  On my computer, it looks something like this:

```
> /Applications/Mist.app/Contents/MacOS/Mist --rpc ~/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc
```

Note: you need to change the paths above to correspond with where those files are on your computer and where you're calling them from, as well as the network.

The geth.ipc file is only created/shows up after you have started geth.

---

For example, another example of this with testnet is:

Terminal 1

```
> geth --testnet --mine
```

Terminal 2 (from home folder)

```
> cd /Applications
> Mist.app/Contents/MacOS/Mist --rpc ~/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run command $ps aux | grep "geth"
Then you will see some progress about geth. and you can kill them by command #kill -s 9 "PID number".Then restart the geth.

Comment: Don't kill Geth with `kill -9`. It sends a `SIGKILL`, which could result in a corrupt database. Use either a `SIGTERM` or `SIGINT` signal which can be handled gracefully.